# Newbie question on what the various cool names like Utopic Unicorn

Tags: virtualbox, mac

1. What do these cool names of releases tell me about the release?
2. Which release is appropriate to install on VirtualBox on Mac (10.9.4)

Comment: you can try ubuntu 14.04 trusty thar with mac

Comment: tell me if it helped you

Comment: 1. Not much, but the corresponding blog posts of their inventor may do, for example: [Utopic](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1363), and [Trusty](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1295). 2. There is no special version for Vbox, just try the one your like or dislike.

Comment: 2. I have had a better experience with Debian and VirtualBox on Mac (10.9) than with Ubuntu, for a single reason: with Ubuntu, I had to reinstall the Guest Additions every time the kernel was updated while with Debian, somehow, the Guest Additions modifications just work. They are important to be able to adjust, for example, the size of the VirtualBox window (magically adjusts the resolution of the virtual machine to fit). The 14.04 version of Ubuntu will benefit for long term support and might be the best choice, currently.